# matching coordinates of superimposed fitsfiles

Tags: python, astronomy, astropy, fits

I have 2 different fits files of a region of the sky, fitsFile2 is a small region of what fitsFile1 covers. I want to plot them in a same plot and superimpose the fitsFile2 on its correct location on fitsFile1 but the result is based on their pixel numbers and not the coordinates. I've used both WCS and aplpy for the coordinate and no luck so far. I get this image: [2 fits files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxkV8.png)

The blue map should be a very small part of the other one, but because it has more numbers of pixels, even though it covers a smaller part of the sky, it ends up bigger in the map.

How could I fix this coordinate problem? Thanks.

Here is an example of what I've tried (using wcs):

```
hdulist2 = fits.open(FitsFile2Path)
hdu2 = hdulist2[0]
wcs2 = WCS(hdu2.header)
hdulist1 = fits.open(FitsFile1Path)
hdu1 = IRhdulist1[0]
wcs1 = WCS(hdu1.header)
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(9,6), dpi=120, facecolor= 'w', edgecolor ='k')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs2)
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, hdu1.data.shape[1] - 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, hdu1.data.shape[0] - 0.5)
ra = ax.coords[0]
dec = ax.coords[1]
ra.set_axislabel('RA (degree)')
dec.set_axislabel('Dec (degree)')
ra.grid(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='solid')
dec.grid(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='solid')
ra.display_minor_ticks(True)
dec.display_minor_ticks(True)
ra.set_minor_frequency(10)
plt.imshow(hdu2.data, origin='lower', cmap = 'BrBG', interpolation='nearest') 
plt.imshow(hdu1.data, origin='lower')
plt.title('Test' , fontsize = 12)
plt.savefig(saveFilePath)
```

Comment: @paisanco: Thanks very much for informing me. I just edited my question.

Comment: Would [reproject](http://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) help you?

Comment: @Evert: Yes, it did help! Thanks!